# Play Framework: POST request with parameters

Tags: scala, post, playframework

Looking around in the Internet I've seen different ways of creating POST requests with parameters:

```
WS.url("https://domain.com/xyz").post(
  "param1=value1&param2=value2"
)

WS.url("https://domain.com/xyz").post(Map(
  "param1" -> Seq("value1"),
  "param2" -> Seq("value2")
))

WS.url("https://domain.com/xyz")
  .withQueryString(("param1", "value1"), ("param2", "value2"))
  .post("")
```

Do the code snippets above produce the same POST request? Is it mandatory to specify the content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you have to set the content type depends on the WebService you are using. Some webservices allow you to use a variety of content-types for making requests (often JSON and XML among others).

The first two should produce the same result, the third one probably not, since the data will (should) be added to the url and not to the body of the request.